# Applying Bag of words

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

Hey I am working with bag of words and I am trying to implement  so suppose I have the corpus below but I don't want to use `print( vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense() )` as a vocabulary instead I have one create which goes like 
`{u'all': 0, u'sunshine': 1, u'some': 2, u'down': 3, u'reason': 4}`
How can  I use this vocabulary to generate the matrix?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus = [
'All my cats in a row',
'When my cat sits down, she looks like a Furby toy!',
'The cat from outer space',
'Sunshine loves to sit like this for some reason.'
]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
print( vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense() )
print( vectorizer.vocabulary_ )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate your CountVectorizer using your custom vocabulary and then transform your corpus.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus = [
'All my cats in a row',
'When my cat sits down, she looks like a Furby toy!',
'The cat from outer space',
'Sunshine loves to sit like this for some reason.'
]

vocabulary = {u'all': 0, u'sunshine': 1, u'some': 2, u'down': 3, u'reason': 4}

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)

print( vectorizer.transform(corpus).todense() )
[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1]]

print( vectorizer.vocabulary_ )
{'all': 0, 'sunshine': 1, 'some': 2, 'down': 3, 'reason': 4}
```

Comment: How can I write this to a file for reference ? And use it as a training model? Like :-

Comment: This is outside the scope of your current question. Post a new question if you like.